# Turn a column in a table into merged row in R with integers addition

Tags: r, rstudio

I have this data table which shows incoming calls at a grocery shop. 
The `call time` is when the call came in, the `activity_time` is when the employee started using the software, `activity_des` is the description of the activity done, `call end` is when the call finished, and finally, `activity duration` is the duration of each activity

```
            Date | Call_time | activity_time | activity_des| Call_end | activity_duration
      -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      2017-05-03 | 08:05:53  |   08:06:03    | Online shop | 08:07:03 | 30 
      2017-05-03 | 08:07:30  |   08:08:00    | Transfer    | 08:10:00 | 25
      2017-05-03 | 08:07:30  |   08:08:25    | buy         | 08:10:00 | 35
      2017-05-03 | 08:07:30  |   08:09:00    | receipt     | 08:10:00 | 60
      2017-05-04 | 14:34:10  |   14:40:00    | question    | 14:41:47 | 66 
      2017-05-04 | 14:34:10  |   14:41:06    | question    | 14:41:47 | 39
      ......     |  .....    |     .....     |   .....     |   .....  | ..
```

Desired output

```
            Date | Call_time |      activity_des      | Call_end    | activities_duration
      ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      2017-05-03 | 08:05:53  |   Online shop          | 08:07:03    | 30 
      2017-05-03 | 08:07:30  |   Transfer,buy,receipt | 08:10:00    | 120
      2017-05-04 | 14:34:10  |   question             | 14:41:47    | 105
      ......     |  .....    |          .....         |   .....     | ..
```

So removing the `activity_time` since we don't need it, merging the different `activity_des` in the same call together, and then adding `activitiy_duration` of those merged ones into one value. 
Also, in case there are the same two activities occurring together sequentially (just like `question`), I dont need showing it twice after merging it, just adding the duration time.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` :

```
library(tidyverse)    
activity %>%
  select(-activity_time) %>%
  group_by(Date, Call_time,Call_end) %>%
  summarize(activity_des = paste(activity_des,collapse=", "),
            activity_duration = sum(activity_duration))
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
# # Groups:   Date, Call_time [?]
#         Date Call_time Call_end           activity_des activity_duration
#        <chr>     <chr>    <chr>                  <chr>             <dbl>
# 1 2017-05-03  08:05:53 08:07:03            Online shop                30
# 2 2017-05-03  08:07:30 08:10:00 Transfer, buy, receipt               120
# 3 2017-05-04  14:34:10 14:41:47     question, question               105
```

**data**

```
activity <- read.table(header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,sep="|",text="
Date | Call_time | activity_time | activity_des| Call_end | activity_duration
  2017-05-03 | 08:05:53  |   08:06:03    | Online shop | 08:07:03 | 30 
2017-05-03 | 08:07:30  |   08:08:00    | Transfer    | 08:10:00 | 25
2017-05-03 | 08:07:30  |   08:08:25    | buy         | 08:10:00 | 35
2017-05-03 | 08:07:30  |   08:09:00    | receipt     | 08:10:00 | 60
2017-05-04 | 14:34:10  |   14:40:00    | question    | 14:41:47 | 66 
2017-05-04 | 14:34:10  |   14:41:06    | question    | 14:41:47 | 39")

activity[] <- lapply(activity,trimws)
activity$activity_duration <- as.numeric(activity$activity_duration)
```

Comment: Thank you @Moody_Mudskipper; however, when I tried applying this, it put everything in one row. It did now group it right with the date and call time. Is there a suggestion on why it is happening?

Comment: with this sample data or your real data ? maybe you have `plyr` loaded, it has a `summarize` function that behaves differently. I suggest never loading `plyr` and calling the occiasionally needed function with `plyr::your_fun`, or be careful to load it before `dplyr`

Comment: Yes, I had it loaded and it worked after unloading it. Thank you